# What is the quickest way to add a COM visible event to VB.NET class?

Tags: vb.net, events, visual-studio-2005, com-interop, comvisible

What is the quickest way to add a `COM` visible event to `VB.NET` class?

Is there something in the Visual Studio toolbox or is there a `macro` that will do this?

I am using `VS2005`.

EDIT: In this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.80).aspx, a `GuidAttribute` is specified.  Is this generated by the programmer at design time, or does it need it to to match a GUID elsewhere?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Where does the `GuidAttribute` in that example come from?  Is it something that the programmer generates at the time of writing that code?

Comment: Ask a proper question about it and I'll be happy to post a proper answer.  It doesn't fit in a comment box.

Comment: I have edited my question to include this extra question.